# How do I pause my command window when using the exit function in C++?

Tags: c++

When a user types something, I want my function to stop and display a phrase. My program currently closes out the command window when the user types that specific something, but I want it to pause so the user can see the phrase. Below is my code in question:

```
if (in.peek() != '/')
{
    obj = Rational(top);
    cout << "Bad input format for operator >>. Aborting!" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: `exit()` ends the calling process immediately.  So you need to prompt the user for input, and then actually read the input, such as with `std::cin.get()`, `getch()`, `system("pause")`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Typically a nice way to achieve that is:

```
std::cout << "Press enter to continue" << std::endl;
std::cin.ignore();
```

Comment: Or `cin.get()` instead